# Better explanation of C++ Pointer function?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am working on a problem for my C++ homework that involves pointers. I am not asking for anyone to do my work, but just some help understanding the problem.

The problem is to write a function

```
void sort2(double* p, double* p) //First off I am assuming the second "p" is a typo and       should be a q
```

This function will receive two pointers and sorts the values to which they point. Example, if you call `sort2(&x, &y)` then x <= y after the call.

What I am wondering is, if the pointers are being de-referenced by the function already, am I just comparing x and y and not their memory addresses? If not how do I compare the memory addresses?

Comment: Why would you want to compare their memory addresses? what do you mean by "if the pointers are being de-referenced by the function already"?

Comment: You should compare x and y, not their addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the addresses of the 2x `double` variables, so that the `sort2()` function can *swap* the values at source.

This way, when the sort function is called like so:

```
sort2(&x, &y)
```

The function can access the caller's memory addresses for `x` and `y` and swap the values stored there, if necessary.

However, if the function just took double parameters by *value*, i.e.

```
void sort2(double p1, double p2)
```

then, although the function could still compare and swap the values around, there is no way that `sort2()` could pass BOTH the new values back to its caller with its current signature, since `p1` and `p2` are copied by value onto the stack and will be lost when the function returns.

The sort function accesses the values of the pointer variables by de-referencing them, e.g.

```
if (*p1 > *p2) {
   // swap / sort etc.
   double swap = *p2;
   *p2 = *p1;
   *p1 = swap;
}
```

And yes, you are correct, the second `p` is almost certainly a typo.

Comment: The use of the term `reference` here could be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Declaring a function with like: `void sort2(double *p, double *q) {` takes in two double pointers. When you call the function like this: `sort2(&x, &y)` you are not dereferencing the pointers, but referencing the variables. For example:

```
void sort2(double *p, double *q) {
  some_code;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  double x = 0.2;
  double y = 0.4;
  sort2(&x, &y); //x's and y's addresses in memory are being passed to sort2
  return 0;
}
```

To compare x and y's memory addresses after the fact then you would have to reference them in some sort of condition like this:

```
if(&x <= &y)
  do_something;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void sort2(double* p, double* p)
```

First.This is not de-referencing. The double*'s here only to tell the compiler this function receives two pointer pointing to double type.It is a declaration.

So you are passing the pointer itself to the function here.The memory addresses are stored in p and q in sort2.

Hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are not references. To compare the values stored in the pointers, you use the dereference operator, which is the unary `*`. C++ and C uses a declaration syntax that mimics use. So `double *p` gives the hint that `*p` is of type `double`. Then value of `*p` is the value of the `double` object that was pointed to by `p`. If `p` does not actually point to a valid `double`, the result of the dereference is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Forget programming and pointers for a second, and let's think about a library. There are lots of shelves with lots of books. Each book is located at some specific coordinates. For example, The **Tale of Two Cities** might be on *Aisle P, Shelf 2, Slot 14*; similarly, **Jane Eyre** might be on *Aisle Q, Shelf 13, Slot 1*. Clearly, you want books in the library to be well organized so that they can be found easily.

Now consider a librarian that is tasked with making sure that the books at the aforementioned coordinates are in the right order. The librarian goes to each coordinates, looks at the titles of the books at those coordinates, and determines which one should go first. In our case, the librarian would notice that since *J* comes before *T*, she needs to swap the books.

Your homework is apparently the C++ version of this. The function `sort2` is given two memory addresses (ie, book locations), and it has to make sure that the *contents* of the first location compares correctly against the *contents* of the second location. ("Compares correctly" is generally either "compares less than" or "compares greater than" depending on if you are sorting ascending or descending.)

As for how `sort2` is called, this part is a little more confusing to explain, and my analogy doesn't work perfectly. The variables `x` and `y` are generally thought of as data (eg, contents of a book), but they each also have an associated address (eg, where the book is). If you type `x`, you are asking for the contents of the variable; if you type `&x`, you are asking for the corresponding memory address. Unlike books, computer memory changes all the time (that's part of why computers are so useful, of course). So in this context, `x` and `y` are better thought of as a named piece of memory rather than names for the actual data (eg, they are the names of the locations of the books, rather than the contents of the books). So when you call `sort2(&x, &y)`, the address-of operators make it explicit that you are operating on the *locations* of `x` and `y` rather than their data. After the call, the addresses of `x` and `y` won't have changed, but their contents might have.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In your void sort2(double* p, double* p) function you should name parameters name differently like sort2(double *ptr1,double *ptr2).

Then call sort2(&x, &y);

Inside sort2(double* ptr1, double* ptr2) you can swap or sort what ever u want.